# What is the difference between ui-view in angularjs and ion-nav-view in ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

As you know in angular `ui-router` we use `ui-view` to render an `html` to parent `html`. According to [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#example---name-matching):

```
<!-- index.html -->
<body>
  <div ui-view="filters"></div>
  <div ui-view="tabledata"></div>
  <div ui-view="graph"></div>
</body>
```

`js` file:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('report', {
  views: {
    'filters': { ... templates and/or controllers ... },
    'tabledata': {},
    'graph': {},
  }
})
```

Also in `Ionic` framework we can use this:

```
<ion-nav-view name="filters"></ion-nav-view>
```

What is the diference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is custom Ionic framework directive. You can find detailed description here [ion-nav-view](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/). It has more advance features like tracking history, transitions and much more. It does use AngularUI router.