# Ionic: Tab view not rendered

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

For some reason Tab view is visible at first however, when we navigate to Tab1 after visiting Tab2 html is not visible.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/naNhC5?p=preview

**Route:**

```
.state('home.tabs', {
                cache: false,
                url: '/i',
                views: {
                    'mainContent': {
                        templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
                    }
                }
            })

            .state('home.tabs.tab1', {
                url: '/tab1',
                views: {
                    'tab1': {
                        cache: false,
                        templateUrl: 'tab1.html'
                    }
                }
            })

            .state('home.tabs.tab2', {
                url: '/tab2',
                views: {
                    'tab2': {
                        cache: false,
                        templateUrl: 'tab2.html'
                    }
                }
            })
```

**Tabs Html:**

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-light ">

    <ion-tab title="Tab1" ui-sref="home.tabs.tab1">
        <ion-nav-view  name="tab1"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="Tab2" ui-sref="home.tabs.tab2"> 
        <ui-view name="tab2"></ui-view>
    </ion-tab>    
</ion-tabs>
```

**Tab-1 View:**

```
<ion-view view-title="Tab1">
    <ion-content class="padding has-header">

        <h2>Tab1</h2>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little error in your `tabs.html` file. You need to substitute `ui-view` with `ion-nav-view`:

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-light">
    <ion-tab title="Tab1" ui-sref="home.tabs.tab1">
        <ion-nav-view  name="tab1"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Tab2" ui-sref="home.tabs.tab2"> 
        <ion-nav-view name="tab2"></ion-nav-view> <!-- <<<< -->
    </ion-tab>    
</ion-tabs>
```

[CHECK DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/kx1igItIhvFAEMeSuiSx?p=preview)

Why?

[What is the difference between ui-view in angularjs and ion-nav-view in ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423447/what-is-the-difference-between-ui-view-in-angularjs-and-ion-nav-view-in-ionic)

Comment: Oh!! Yes coming from angular background forgot to change this. It is working alright now. I just wonder why did it not work with ui-view?